# Cannot install Software from the Software-Center

Tags: installation, software-center

I have a problem. I want to install software from the software-center but when I click on "Install" comes a pop-up with this text in German:

*Anscheinend gibt es einen Programmfehler in aptdaemon, der Anwendung, die Ihnen das Installieren/Entfernen von Anwendungen und das Ausführen weiterer Paketverwaltungsaufgaben ermöglicht.*

In details:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 968, in simulate
    trans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1092, in _simulate_helper
    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 235, in required_download
    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)
SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate a file for the libwww-robotrules-perl package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.
```

Sorry for this question. I have Ubuntu since two days and my English is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schließe das Software-Center. Öffne ein Terminal (<kbd>Windows</kbd>-Taste und `Ter...` eintippen) und führe folgenden Befehl aus: `sudo apt-get install -f`. Gib auf Nachfrage dein Passwort ein. Wenn das erfolgreich ist, kannst du es erneut mit dem Softwarecenter versuchen.

In English: Close Software-Center. Open a Terminal. Run `sudo apt-get install -f`. Enter your password if asked. Then open Software-Center again.

Comment: Da stand ich soll sudo dpkg --configure -a eingeben habe ich gemacht dann scannt er was dann kommt Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: habe ich mit ja beantwortet

Comment: dann scannt er vieles

Comment: dann kommt ne elents lange EULA aber da steht ok ich klicke aber nichts passiert was soll ich machen

Comment: Was versuchst du denn zu installieren?